# add option on right click menu of textview Gtk+ python

Tags: python, gtk3, gnome

I want to add one more option in the default menu comes on right click in textview in Gtk+ Python.

On hovering of that option I want to add one more submenu/popup to that option.

How it is possible in Gtk+ Python2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect to the [`populate-popup`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/TextView.html#Gtk.TextView.signals.populate_popup) signal, and add your menu item to the `Gtk.Menu` that is passed to your signal handler.